# "Couldn't load file functions/bar.mcfunction in functions directory."

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

I made two function files:

```
tag @e[tag="xf_selected"] remove "xf_selected"
tag @e[c=1] add "xf_selected"
```

and

```
tag @e[tag="xf_selected"] remove "xf_selected"
tag @e add "xf_selected"
```

And that's it. I've tested the commands and they are valid. I get the following errors:

```
[Commands][warning]-Couldn't load file functions/selectentity/all.mcfunction in functions directory.


[Commands][warning]-Couldn't load file functions/selectentity/nearest.mcfunction in functions directory.
```

What's wrong and how can I fix it? - I literally have nothing else in the pack except for the manifest (which seems to be working).

Comment: It does not produce an error message or tell you what went wrong?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 thats the errors and all thats in the logs

Comment: If you change up the commands, does it start working, but then stops once you change it to what is here?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 i literally made it `say hi` and it still fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `functions` directory was called `Functions` by mistake (I blame you .NET)!

Make sure your directory is named `functions`.

Answer (score -3):

The function file on your PC or device might be corrupted. Bridge automatically creates these function commands with my experience with it. You might want to try to factory reset your PC.

Comment: wait what if u downgrade to an older version of minecraft since my older addons still work  try that too.

Comment: Decent answer, but please try not to add comments like "*don't trust me on this*", as that will make people **not** want to use your answer.

Comment: I really would not recommend factory resetting your PC because Minecraft can't find a file; chances are if this happens to you it is on you (look I literally just named the directory wrong).